# How to improve or customize anti-aliasing of fonts for Qt applications?

Tags: c++, css, qt, fonts, antialiasing

I'm using **Qt 4.8 for embedded linux** and view my application on the device display as well as on my desktop using the **-qws** flag.

When using a white font above a blue background I experience that the font is really thin and hard to read. This happens only on the hardware/device because we have a limited bit-depth per channel there.

The reason for this is simply the distance between the colors: *black (0,0,0)* on *white (255,255,255)* has a larger distance than *white (255,255,255)* on *blue (100,160,250)* so the contrast is just smaller. When the anti-aliasing algorithm computes values between the two colors the outer pixels might have values too close to the background. Take a look at the pointed to pixels in my image: the gray one (stemming from black) above the white background can be seen better than the gray one (stemming from white) above the blue background:

[image: Anti aliased fonts with different colors and backgrounds]

On my PC's display it looks still fine. Since the hardware of the device looses precision of the color channels (5 to 6 bits instead of 8) the effect is huge and the font looks ugly.

What I'm interested in:

- Can I do anything about the anti-aliasing algorithm, maybe change parameters so that the "contrast" is increased? For example, the anit-aliasing could use the pixel-perfect font and only "smear" it outwards instead of dampening the intenisty of present pixels.
- Should I use pre-rendered fonts in contrast to true type fonts? I compiled **Qt for embedded** with **TTF** support and like it because I have access to more fonts this way but should I be using another format like Qt's **PFA** or **PFB**?
- Should I simply ask my designer to give me another (maybe thicker) font or to change the background color to a darker one? This of course is not preferred ;-)

Comment: Does your hardware have conventional LCD RGB screens? You may want to research subpixel rendering.

Comment: @MSalters: Thanks for the hint, it basically increases the horizontal resolution of an LCD display if the separate RGB elements are positioned horizontally. This, of course, has the drawback of a color-shift. Do you have more specific information about Qt and the rendering there? I question that it is available or easy to implement?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't need to cause a color shift. Assuming one pure white pixel on pure blue, you can do `..B..BRGB..B..B..` but also `..B.GBR.B..B..B..` - this shifts the white pixel by less than one integer position. No idea if Qt supports this directly, though.

Comment: Yes, but this is an edge case :-) In usual scenarios a color-shift is introduced. Nevertheless, thanks for the hint.